# show/hide divs based on hasClass('active') of corresponding anchors

Tags: jquery, html

HTML markup : the Triggers

```
<li class="divider"></li>

<li class="has-dropdown active" id="calloutButton"><a><img style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" src="img/at.png"><span class="label">2</span></a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>

<li class="has-dropdown" id="hashtagButton"><a><img style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" src="img/hashtag.png"><span class="label">3</span></a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>

<li class="has-dropdown" id="messagesButton"><a><img style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" src="img/mail.png"><span class="label">5</span></a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>
```

The container divs:

```
 <div id="messages-pop-up">Foo bar</div>
 <div id="hashtag-pop-up">New bar</div>
 <div id="callout-pop-up">Lube bar</div>
```

And the Jquery:

```
 $('li#messagesButton').click(function(h) {
                $('div#messages-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
            });
 $('li#hashtagButton').click(function(j) {
                $('div#hashtag-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
            });
 $('li#calloutButton').click(function(k) {
                $('div#callout-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
            });
```

You can see the problem , they all can be open at the same time and are overlapping .Because I am using Foundation when I click on a `li` it attributes the class `active` and I want the other to close when one is opened . I wouldn't want to change the html markup but if there's no other way around it I'll comply.

Comment: could you might provide us with a jsfiddle ? btw you may have a look at http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways

1 - By adding a class to the three  and hiding all div with the class on every click event before the slidedown.

Add class pop-out-div to all div.

```
$('li#messagesButton').click(function(h) {
    $(".pop-out-div").hide();
    $('div#messages-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
});
$('li#hashtagButton').click(function(j) {
    $(".pop-out-div").hide();
    $('div#hashtag-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
});
$('li#calloutButton').click(function(k) {
    $(".pop-out-div").hide();
    $('div#callout-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
});
```

2 - Hiding all other div except the one that needs to be open.

```
$('li#messagesButton').click(function(h) {
    $('div#hashtag-pop-up').hide();
    $('div#callout-pop-up').hide();
    $('div#messages-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
});
$('li#hashtagButton').click(function(j) {
    $('div#messages-pop-up').hide();
    $('div#callout-pop-up').hide();
    $('div#hashtag-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
});
$('li#calloutButton').click(function(k) {
    $('div#hashtag-pop-up').hide();
    $('div#messages-pop-up').hide();
    $('div#callout-pop-up').stop().slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what you are looking for is **[accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)**, this will close  others if one gets opened. Of corse you have to redesign your source a lil bit but actually this does what it has to do and may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes , I know about accordion , but I've had issues with it , I don't know if it's because of foundation or something else , but it wouldn't work , although I included the necessary snippets

Answer (score 0):

Try this , adding data-* to html and use with jQuery

1,Change HTML to

```
<li class="divider"></li>

<li class="has-dropdown active" id="calloutButton" data-content-wrapper="messages-pop-up"><a><img style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" src="img/at.png"><span class="label">2</span></a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>

<li class="has-dropdown" id="hashtagButton" data-content-wrapper="hashtag-pop-up"><a><img style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" src="img/hashtag.png"><span class="label">3</span></a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>

<li class="has-dropdown" id="messagesButton" data-content-wrapper="callout-pop-up"><a><img style="height: 25px; width: 25px;" src="img/mail.png"><span class="label">5</span></a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>
```

Then script to

```
$("li").click(function () {
                var CurrentActive = $(this).parent().children(".active");
                if (CurrentActive != undefined && CurrentActive != null) {
                    CurrentActive.removeClass("active");
                    $('#' + CurrentActive.data('content-wrapper')).hide();
                }
                $(this).addClass("active");

                $('#' + $(this).data('content-wrapper')).stop().slideDown();


            });
```

I think this may work for you

Comment: I'll give it a try , and I'll let you know.